# Differential Geometry Normal curvature and the Weingarten map

Tags: differential-geometry

I have two questions related the the surface $S$, 
$$x(u,v) =(u,v,u^2 + uv)$$
which I was hoping somebody might be able to help with:

1. Give the normal curvature of $S$ at the point $x(0,0)$ in the direction $dx/du + dv/du$.

I think I need to use Meusnier's theorem but I'm not sure how.

2. Find the principe directions of $S$ at $x(0,0)$.

I have calculated the first and second fundamental forms at this point to be $E=1$ , $F=0$, $G=1$, $L=2$, $M=1$, $N=0$, this gives me a matrix for the Weigengarten map to be 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Are the eigenvectors of this matrix the directions I am looking for?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For 1) you want Euler's formula for normal curvature. For 2), yes, you're precisely correct.